# Checking FirebaseData is returning null for no reason

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have an app that checks when my users are logging into the app if they have data , so , if the data is found in the database the user can work with his data, so if the user uninstalls the app, or lost the phone , the data will be there even if they install the app in another device. I solved this problem just by making a request and saying "ok, if the data is != than null , there is data to be downloaded"

so, this is working fine if i dont uninstall the app and only change between users, if i move between different accounts , the data is retrieved for each user, but the failure is that my app access to the else statment of my database files checking and i dont know why

My shared preferences are ok, because if there is not shared preferences i use the locale string as my URL_xxx_"" , so there is no reason to be a problem there , because if i uninstall the app , the shared preferences are erased from the phone but i will be using the locale language if i reinstall the app.

Here is where i check if the user has some data, if they have some data i retrieve this data and store it into internall memory, where i access it later.

```
 private void CheckIfDataExists(){    
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("URL_UserFiles").child("URL_planes_"+sharedPrefsDefault.getString(getString(R.string.str_language),locale)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshotPlanes) {

                mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("URL_UserFiles").child("URL_cars_"+sharedPrefsDefault.getString(getString(R.string.str_language),locale)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotCars) {

                        if (dataSnapshotPlanes.getValue()!=null && dataSnapshotCars.getValue()!=null) {

                            Log.e("Descarga","DATA EXISTS");


                            File rootPath = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(),"APP_FILES");
                            if(!rootPath.exists()) {
                                rootPath.mkdirs();
                            }

                            StorageReference mStorageRefUsuariosPlanes = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("User_Files").child("planes").child("planes_" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail() + "_" + sharedPrefsDefault.getString(getString(R.string.str_language),"en") + "." + "txt");
                            StorageReference mStorageRefUsuariosCars = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("User_Files").child("cars").child("cars_" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail() + "_" + sharedPrefsDefault.getString(getString(R.string.str_language),"en") + "." + "txt");

                            final File carsUsuarioFile = new File(rootPath, "cars.txt");
                            final File planesUsuarioFile = new File(rootPath, "planes.txt");

                            mStorageRefUsuariosCars.getFile(carsUsuarioFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    Log.e("TamañoArchivo",""+taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                    Log.e("NombreArchivo",""+carsUsuarioFile);

                                    try {

                                        FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("cars.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        fos.write(getStringFromFile(carsUsuarioFile.getAbsolutePath()).getBytes());
                                        Log.e("CARSFILEUSUARIO",""+getStringFromFile(carsUsuarioFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                                        fos.close();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    obsInt.set(obsInt.get()+1);
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                }
                            });

                            mStorageRefUsuariosPlanes.getFile(planesUsuarioFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    Log.e("FileSize",""+taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                    Log.e("NombreArchivo",""+planesUsuarioFile);

                                    try {
                                        FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("planes.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        fos.write(getStringFromFile(planesUsuarioFile.getAbsolutePath()).getBytes());
                                        Log.e("PLANESFILE",""+getStringFromFile(gruposUsuarioFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                                        Log.e("obsintUsuarios",""+obsInt);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Log.e("printStackTrace",""+e.toString());

                                    }
                                    obsInt.set(obsInt.get()+1);
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("printStackTrace",""+e.toString());
                                }

                            });

                        }else{
                            Log.e("Descarga2","DATA DOES NOT EXIST");
                            locale = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
                            Log.e("LENGUAGE",""+locale);
                            sharedPrefsDefault.edit().putString(getString(R.string.str_language), locale).apply();

                            File rootPath = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(),"APP_FILES");
                            if(!rootPath.exists()) {
                                rootPath.mkdirs();//si no existe el directorio lo creamos
                            }

                            StorageReference mStorageRefPlanes = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Country_Data/planes/" + "planes_" + locale + "." + "txt");
                            StorageReference mStorageRefCars = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Country_Data/cars/" + "cars_" + locale + "." + "txt");
                            Log.e("REFERENCIACARS",""+ mStorageRefCars);
                            Log.e("REFERENCIAGPLANES",""+ mStorageRefPlanes);

                            final File carsFile = new File(rootPath, "cars.txt");
                            final File planesFile = new File(rootPath, "planes.txt");

                            mStorageRefCars.getFile(carsFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    Log.e("FileSize",""+taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                    Log.e("NombreArchivo",""+carsFile);

                                    try {

                                        FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("cars.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        fos.write(getStringFromFile(carsFile.getAbsolutePath()).getBytes());
                                        Log.e("CARSFILEDESCARGARPAIS",""+getStringFromFile(carsFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                                        fos.close();


                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    obsInt.set(obsInt.get()+1);

                                }

                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                }



                            });

                            mStorageRefPlanes.getFile(planesFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    Log.e("FileSize",""+taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                    Log.e("NombreArchivo",""+planesFile);

                                    try {
                                        FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("planes.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        fos.write(getStringFromFile(gruposFile.getAbsolutePath()).getBytes());
                                        Log.e("PLANESFILEDESCARGARPAIS",""+getStringFromFile(gruposFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                                        fos.close();


                                        Log.e("obsintPaises",""+obsInt);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Log.e("printStackTrace",""+e.toString());

                                    }

                                    obsInt.set(obsInt.get()+1);
                                }

                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                    Log.e("printStackTrace",""+e.toString());
                                }

                            });


                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: either i am not understanding the problem...or something else. but if you login, you store that information into shared pref. you log out, login to another account, your else statements get hit. do you remove the sharepref from the previous logged in user?

Comment: nope, if i logout and login with other accounts thats fine, the data is stored for each one and retrieved, the problem is when i uninstall the app and enter with an account, it launches the else statment and the data is in firebase, there is no need to launch the else statment if there is data.. @DroiDev

Comment: if you uninstall the app, the data is uninstalled with it... therefore, it will first get it from firebase....

Comment: yes, the data from sharedprefs getString.str_language, but if i reinstall it it should load locale data, and that data is the same in my database, so i dont get why it dosnt load it

Comment: also, every onStop i store the data into firebase, so if you leave the app or uninstall it closing it it will store the latest data

Comment: no it wont. how would it? you uninstalled it. think about it. its not like having a word document on your computer and if you uninstall word and then reinstall it works fine. you are storing that data attached to that app. its the same thing as clearing the cache on your browser. if you delete google chrome, and reinstall it, your bookmarks wont come back... UNLESS you export them....

Comment: but think about this, if you have data in spanish stored at your database, and your locale is in spanish too, if you uninstall the app and reinstall it, the locale is placing the link to the database to go and try to find if there is data for you in your language, and if there is not you will be downloading the default data.. thats what happening to me, im downloading default data but i have that locale data stored there...

Comment: then i would reccomend looking at your logic. lets keep this simple. Im a new user. I change my profile to read "i love code" I hit save. it saves to local. i delete the app, i install, "i love code" will not show in the app because it was never saved to firebase, it was saved to local. do you follow?

Comment: dude, thanks for caring,  i have just found the problem, i was accessing another locale variable from above my method and i needed to put the locale i want inside my method

Comment: i wasn't really looking at your code to have seen that root cause....but im glad my "logic" comment helped. :) happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for passing by and thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that in my else statment i was defining my locale this way

```
locale = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

but at the begining of my `CheckIfDataExists()`  method i was using a locale from the oncreate, that locale had another sintax so i was never able to reach my database

so, i was using this at the begining of the method

```
locale = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() +"-"+ Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country();
```

this input was returning es-ARG  and i needed only es , so i just added the `getDefault().getLanguage();` only and it worked